# Adding a WSP through the Management Shell?

Tags: powershell, solution-package

I have a WSP that I am trying to install on my development SharePoint server.  I used the Management Shell to do this:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath c:\temp\mySolution.wsp
```

and then:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity mySolution.wsp -WebApplication http://sp-dev:10000 -GACDeployment
```

But when I go to `Site Settings->Solutions` there is nothing present in the Solution Gallery.  Is this not where my WSPs get installed?

UPDATE:

I un-selected @Renzo's answer because from what I can tell `-WebApplication http://sp-dev:10000` adds it to the web application.  Shouldn't I be seeing this in the `Site Settings->Solutions` area now?

Comment: Did you check that the deployment succeeded with `Enum-Deployments`?

Comment: No need for stsadm: `Get-SPSolution | select DisplayName, LastOperationResult` :-)

Comment: Don't mix up farm solutions (SPSolution) ans user/sandboxed solutions (SPUserSolution). Only the latter you would see in Site Settings > Solutions (gallery). The former would only appear in Central Administration's Manage farm solutions area as Renzo said below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing that you are deploying your solutions to the farm and therefor you can find it if you go to

- Central Administration
- System Settings
- Farm Management > Farm Solutions

If you want to deploy it to sandbox solution using powershell then your solution will need to be sandbox solution compatible and you can use the following command

- Install-SPUserSolution -Identity yourSolution.wsp -Site http://yourSite

Hope this helps

Comment: Shouldn't the `-WebApplication http://sp-dev:10000` install it to my `Site Settings->Solutions` for `http://sp-dev:10000`?

Comment: No web application will deploy it at farm level and when you go to site settings> solutions you will only see sand box solutions NOT farm solutions

Comment: Interesting, so can I still use the web part on my sites if I have it deployed as a Farm solution or do I need to deploy it as a sand box solution?

Comment: You can do anything with a farm solution. On the other hand for sandbox solution you are restricted to only supported things. eg: you not alllow to elevate code in sandbox solutions, if you browse the sharepoint api on msdn it will tell you on the top if its available for use in sandbox solution or not.

Comment: You are welcome! feels good to be useful!

Answer (score 1):

Why Site Settings->Solutions? If you are not deploying sandboxed applications your application should not be listed in solutions gallery. Please open solution gallery and add your WSP package. SharePoint should give you an error message. Open site collection features and you should be able to actiate your solution. After that it can be used like any webpart.